# c++: volatile member function in volatile instance - assigning array to pointer is invalid conversion?

Tags: c++, volatile, member-functions

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
    int intArray[2] { 1, 2 };
    int *firstElementPt;

    public:
        int getFirstElement() volatile {
            firstElementPt = intArray;
            return *firstElementPt;
        };
};

int main()
{
    volatile C c;
    std::cout << c.getFirstElement();
}
```

This gives me the following compilation error:

```
 In member function 'int C::getFirstElement() volatile':
10:28: error: invalid conversion from 'volatile int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

I'm new to C++. I read that declaring an instance as volatile would implicitly make all it's member variables volatile. And I read that declaring a member function as volatile would mean to mark the hidden `*this`pointer as volatile. So why is the assignment `firstElementPt = intArray;` still not allowed and leads to `error: invalid conversion from 'volatile int*' to 'int*'`?

Comment: As someone who is new to C++ you should simply forget that `volatile` exists. You won't ever need it.

Comment: `int *` means pointer to non-volatile int . In a volatile class this would be a volatile pointer to non-volatile int. The same "problem" would occur with s/volatile/const

Comment: @M.M no problem with a const, you cannot assign one anyway.

Comment: @n.m. What about variables accessed both from an ISR and from "main" code in an Arduino program? That's my use-case...

Comment: @x-ray — `volatile` is not the right tool for that. There’s a host of multi-threading support classes and functions for that.

Comment: @PeteBecker That is an interesting comment, as it contradicts what I found in other sources. [The Arduino language reference explicitly mentions use of `volatile` for variables used in ISRs.](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/variable-scope--qualifiers/volatile/). And I found [some](https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4025583/Use-volatile-judiciously) [more](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword) [articles](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/28) elaborating on this. Could you point to such classes for Arduino?

Comment: It may work specifically in Arduino or perhaps other machines with a single CPU core, bit it is generally not portable. Most often one uses volatile for memory mapped hardware registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volatility and constness do not propagate through pointers, but they do propagate through arrays. So in a volatile instance of the class, `firstElementPt` is itself volatile, but the thing it points to is not. The `intArray` elements however are volatile. You are attempting to point a volatile-pointer-to-a-non-volatile-int to a `volatile int`. This is not allowed.

Comment: Is there a way to make the compiler treat `firstElementPt` as a volatile-pointer-to-a-volatile-int within `getFirstElement()`?